# Pandas rolling apply with variable window length

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Series with values indexed by timestamps. These timestamps are irregularly spaced and I would like to calculate something like the rolling mean (say) over the last N seconds, where N is a constant. Unfortunately, resampling at regular intervals before calculating the rolling quantity is NOT an option - the rolling quantity has to be calculated on the entire dataset.

Is there a good way to do this in pandas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pandas: rolling mean by time interval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15771472/pandas-rolling-mean-by-time-interval)

Answer (score 3):

You want to reset your index to an integer index and perform the rolling operation on a timestamp column.

```
# generate some data
data = pd.DataFrame(data={'vals':range(5), 'seed_ts': [np.datetime64('2017-04-13T09:00:00') for x in range(5)]})
data['random_offset'] = [np.timedelta64(randint(0, 5), 's') for x in range(5)]
data['cum_time'] = data['random_offset'].cumsum()
data['ts'] = data['seed_ts'] + data['cum_time']
data.index = data['ts']
data = data[['vals']]
```

Reset the index:

```
data = data.reset_index()
```

Compute the rolling mean over the past 5 seconds:

```
data['rolling_mean'] = data.rolling('5s', on='ts')['vals'].mean()
```