# IPython / pandas: Is there an canonical way to detect rapid changes in a timeseries?

Tags: pandas, ipython

Noob data analyst, analyzing some gas concentrations over a timeseries of a couple of thousand points (so small). I graphed it with Matplotlib, and there are some easy to see points where things change rapidly.

What is the canonical / easiest way to home in on those points?

Comment: Do you mean comparing values against previous value? `diff()` shows the difference between previous rows if that's any help

Comment: I am comparing values to earlier values in the time series. Say comparing n with n-10.

Comment: Yeah, like Ed said.  Check out diff().  Maybe filter on the bigger values to slim down what you're looking at.  There's also rolling_mean that could help identify more sustained spikes

Comment: like Bob said, rolling_mean of the diff, and I'd spend some time with the window size for rolling_mean while deciding what I meant by "rapidly".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import diff, concatenate
ff = pd.DataFrame( #acquire data here
      columns=('Year','Recon'))
fd = diff(ff['Recon'], axis=-1)
ff['diff'] = concatenate([[0],fd],axis=0)
ff['rolling10'] = pd.rolling_mean(ff['diff'],10)
ff['rolling5'] = pd.rolling_mean(ff['diff'],5)
ff.plot('Year',['rolling5','rolling10'],subplots=False)
```

*But note*! my test data was evenly sampled. Looks like `rolling_*` don't apply to irregular time series yet, though there are some workarounds: [Pandas: rolling mean by time interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15771472/pandas-rolling-mean-by-time-interval?rq=1)