# Smoothing in Python

Tags: python, numpy, convolution, smoothing

I often use a time averaged view for my data so that it is less noisy when I plot it. For example, if my data is taken every 1 minute, then I have two arrays, `ts` and `ys`. I then created `fs` which is a local averaging of the 60 nearest points in `ys`. I do this convolution myself by simply calculating the average of the 60 nearest points, so I don't use any modules from `numpy` or anything else.

I have new data where `ts` is a bit more sparse. That is, sometimes I miss some datapoints and so I can't simply take an average of the 60 nearest points. If my independent variable, `ts`, is in minutes, how do I calculate an hourly average of my dependent variable, `ys`, to create an hourly average function, `fs`, in `python`?

Comment: This may be a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15771472/pandas-rolling-mean-by-time-interval

Comment: Anything wrong with just taking the points from within +/- 30 minutes, summing them and dividing by the count?

Comment: That's kind of what I ended up doing. I'll post my solution below.

Comment: I don't know why this was marked as a duplicate.  The supposedly antecedent question involves pandas and is far more specialized than this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating an array representing the data in terms of the unit of time I was interested in and then performing statistics on that array. An example is to create the 'minute' time into an 'hour' time and work with the average value of `ys` within that hour:

```
for i in range(len(ts0)):
    tM = ts0[i] # time in minutes
    tH = tM/60.0 # time in hours

    tHs[i] = int(tH) # now this is the data within hour tH

tHs0 = tHs[:] # keep a record of the original hourly times, there are repeats here
tHs = list(set(tHs0)) # now we have a list of the hours with no repeats

for i in range(len(ts0)):
    y0 = ys0[i]
    t0 = ts0[i]
    tH = int(t0/60.0)
    ys[tHs.index(tH)] += R0
    Cs[tHs.index(tH)] += 1 # keep a record of how many times this was seen

for i in range(len(ys)):
    ys[i] = ys[i]/Cs[i]
```

Answer (score 3):

> If my independent variable, ts, is in minutes, how do I calculate an hourly average of my dependent variable, ys, to create an hourly average function, fs, in python?

This is a complex problem and possible answers vary widely depending on what you mean by "hourly average".

One approach to dealing with irregularly-spaced data is to resample it.  The resampling could be done with interpolation, and the resulting resampled data is then usable for whatever filter method that you like.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
%matplotlib inline

def y(t):
    # a function to simulate data
    return np.sin(t/20.) + 0.05*np.random.randn(len(t))

four_hours = np.arange(240)
random_time_points = np.sort(np.random.choice(four_hours, size=30, replace=False))

simulated_data = y(random_time_points)
resampled_data = np.interp(four_hours, random_time_points, simulated_data)

# here I smooth with a Savitzky-Golay filter, 
#  but you could use a moving avg or anything else
#  the window-length=61 means smooth over a 1-hour (60 minute) window
smoothed_data = savgol_filter(resampled_data, window_length=61, polyorder=0)

# plot some results
plt.plot(random_time_points, simulated_data, '.k', 
         four_hours, smoothed_data, '--b',
         four_hours, y(four_hours), '-g')

# save plot
plt.savefig('SO35038933.png')
```

[image: Plot of data]

The plot shows original "sparse" data (black points), the original "true" data (green curve), and the smoothed data (blue dotted curve).

Comment: Unfortunately my data was too large and this solution became so memory intensive that it wasn't viable.

Comment: How many time points are in your data?  If memory is limiting there is no reason that the data couldn't be broken into chunks, and the process I describe applied to each chunk.

Comment: True. For that matter there is no reason that I can't write this in C using MPI and put it on a non-uniform memory architecture where the memory can be spread out among several hosts. Unfortunately dev time is a factor and I am using python for a quick and dirty solution with minimal hassle.

Comment: And to answer your question ... lots

Comment: If you are confused about how to chunk the data check SO for some ideas.  It's a pretty common tactic.

Comment: Thanks - not a confusion issue, just a time constraint issue.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, I think something like this may work.

```
import threading    

hours_worth_of_data = []    
def timer():
  threading.Timer(3600, timer).start()  #3600 seconds in an hour
  smooth = sum(hours_worth_of_data) / len(hours_worth_of_data)
  # do something with smooth here
  del hours_worth_of_data[:]  #Start over with fresh data for next hour
timer()
```

Whenever you get your data, also load the data into "hours_worth_of_data." Every hour it will average the data then delete the data inside of your list.