# Pandas: Rolling time-weighted moving average with Groupby

Tags: python, pandas, weighted-average

I have the following dataframe of customer sales history (it's just part of it, the actual dataframe is more than 70k rows):

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as DT

df_test = pd.DataFrame({
    'Cus_ID': ["T313","T348","T313","T348","T313","T348","T329","T329","T348","T313","T329","T348"],
    'Value': [3,2,3,4,5,3,7.25,10.25,4.5,11.75,6.25,6],
    'Date' : [
        DT.datetime(2015,10,18),
        DT.datetime(2015,11,14),
        DT.datetime(2015,11,18),
        DT.datetime(2015,12,13),
        DT.datetime(2015,12,19),
        DT.datetime(2016,1,24),
        DT.datetime(2016,1,31),
        DT.datetime(2016,2,17),
        DT.datetime(2016,3,28),
        DT.datetime(2016,3,31),
        DT.datetime(2016,4,3),            
        DT.datetime(2016,4,16),            
    ]})
```

I would like to add a new column to the dataframe to show the result of time-weighted average of the last 90 days for that customers.

Expected result (column `Value_Result`):

```
     Cus_ID   Date    Value    Value_Result   
0    T313 2015-10-18   3.00          NaN      (No 90days history)
1    T348 2015-11-14   2.00          NaN      (No 90days history)
2    T313 2015-11-18   3.00            3      (3*31)/31
3    T348 2015-12-13   4.00            2      (2*29)/29
4    T313 2015-12-19   5.00            3      (3*62+3*31)/(62+31)
5    T348 2016-01-24   3.00        2.743      (4*42+2*71)/(42+71)
6    T329 2016-01-31   7.25          NaN      (No 90days history)
7    T329 2016-02-17  10.25         7.25      (7.25*17)/17
8    T348 2016-03-28   4.50            3      (3*64)/64
9    T313 2016-03-31  11.75          NaN      (No 90days history)
10   T329 2016-04-03   6.25        8.516      (10.25*46+7.25*63)/(46+63)
11   T348 2016-04-16   6.00        3.279      (4.5*19+3*83)/(19+83)
```

I've tried to use `groupby('Cus_ID')` and the rolling apply, but I have difficulty writing the function to only consider 90 days backward.

Any input highly appreciated.

Comment: Similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15771472/5276797). One option is to resample daily (that's the accepted answer). If resampling is not an option, another answer provides an ad-hoc function to apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure the rolling function will be the way to go with a weighted average, although maybe someone else knows how to use it for that
I can't promise this will be the most optimized method but it will yield the result you want, you can take this and build upon it if necessary.

Big thanks to this [pbpython article](http://pbpython.com/weighted-average.html). I recommend reading through it.

My approach is to create a function that will be applied to groups (group by Cus_ID). This function will iterate over rows in that group and do the weighted averaging as you describe above, apply this back to the group and return the group. This code snippet is verbose for clarity of explination, you can trim it down by removing all the creation of the variables if desired.

The apply function looks like this

```
def tw_avg(group, value_col, time_col, new_col_name="time_weighted_average", days_back='-90 days', fill_value=np.nan):
"""
Will calculate the weighted (by day) time average of the group passed.
It will not operate on the day it is evaulating but the previous days_back.
Should be used with the apply() function in Pandas with groupby function


Args:
    group (pandas.DataFrame): Will be passed by pandas
    value_col (str): Name of column with value to be averaged by weight
    time_col (str): Name of column of with times in them
    new_col_name (str): Name of new column to place time weighted average into, default: time_weighted_average
    days_back (str): Time delta description as described in panda time deltas documentation, default: -90 days
    fill_value (any): The value to fill rows which do not have data in days_back period, default: np.nan

Returns:
    (pandas.DataFrame): The modified DataFrame with time weighted average added to columns, np.nan if no
    time weight average exist
"""
for idx, row in group.iterrows():
    # Filter for only values that are days_back for averaging.
    days_back_fil = (group[time_col] < row[time_col]) & (group[time_col] >= row[time_col] + pd.Timedelta(days_back))
    df = group[days_back_fil] 

    df['days-back'] = (row[time_col] - df[time_col]) / np.timedelta64(1, 'D') # need to divide by np.timedelta day to get number back
    df['weight'] = df[value_col] * df['days-back']

    try:
        df['tw_avg'] = df['weight'].sum() / df['days-back'].sum()
        time_avg = df['tw_avg'].iloc[0] # Get single value of the tw_avg
        group.loc[idx, new_col_name] = time_avg
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        group.loc[idx, new_col_name] = fill_value     

return group
```

You can then return the DataFrame you're looking for with this line

```
df_test.groupby(by=['Cus_ID']).apply(tw_avg, 'Value', 'Date')
```

This will yield,

```
    Cus_ID  Date        Value  time_weighted_average
0   T313    2015-10-18  3.0    NaN
1   T348    2015-11-14  2.0    NaN
2   T313    2015-11-18  3.0    3.0
3   T348    2015-12-13  4.0    2.0
4   T313    2015-12-19  5.0    3.0
5   T348    2016-01-24  3.0    2.743362831858407
6   T329    2016-01-31  7.25   NaN  
7   T329    2016-02-17  10.25  7.25
8   T348    2016-03-28  4.5    3.0
9   T313    2016-03-31  11.75  NaN  
10  T329    2016-04-03  6.25   8.51605504587156
11  T348    2016-04-16  6.0    3.2794117647058822
```

You can now use that function to apply weighted average to other value columns with the `value_col` argument or change the time window length with `days_back` argument. See pandas [time deltas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html) page for how to describe time deltas.

Comment: Hi Josh, really thanks so much! This is really what I needed !