# How to use Pandas rolling average without guaranteed number of observations

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, statistics

I am looking at annualized baseball statistics and would like to calculate a rolling mean looking back at the previous 3 years' worth of performance in regard to number of Hits. However, I want to account for the fact that while my dataset reaches back more than 3 years, one single player may have only been in the league for 1-2 years and will not have 3 years' worth of observations off of which I can calculate the rolling mean. For example:

```
In[6]: df = pd.DataFrame({'PLAYER_ID': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], 
                          'HITS': [45, 55, 50, 20, 24]})
In[9]: df
Out[9]: 
  PLAYER_ID  HITS
0         A    45
1         A    55
2         A    50
3         B    20
4         B    24
```

How would I use a groupby and aggregation/transform (or some other process) to calculate the rolling mean for each player **with a max 3 years historic totals** and then just use the max available historic observations for a player with less than 3 years' historic performance data available?

Pretty sure my answer lies within the Pandas package but would be interested in any solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure a rolling mean is actually what you want? With only one to three observations per player, this data is too sparse for a rolling mean to be particularly meaningful.

Comment: It was annualized for simplicity of explanation. I'll be doing this on game level data along with some other things.

Comment: What's your [sampling frequency](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#resampling)?

Comment: Does sampling frequency impact how I ensure I only look back so far as I have available data for every Player ID? My example was for simplicity of explanation.

Comment: Another discussion you may find interesting is here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15771472

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pd.DataFrame.rolling` handles this problem for you automatically. Using your example data, `df.groupby('PLAYER_ID').rolling(1).mean()` will give you:

```
             HITS PLAYER_ID
PLAYER_ID
A         0  45.0         A
          1  55.0         A
          2  50.0         A
B         3  20.0         B
          4  24.0         B
```

For your example case I'm using a window size of just 1, which means that we're treating each individual observation as its own mean. This isn't particularly interesting. With more data you can use a larger window size: for example, if your data is weekly, `rolling(5)` would give you an approximately monthly window size (or `rolling(31)` if your data is daily, and so on).

Two issues to be aware of when using this methodology:

1. If your data isn't sampled on a regular basis (e.g. if it skips a week or a month at a time), your rolling average won't be aligned in time. For this reason if your data isn't already regularly sampled you'll usually want to resample it.
2. If your data contains `NaN` values, those will be propagated: every window containing that `NaN` will also be `NaN`. You'll have to [impute those values](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html) somehow to keep that from happening.

Comment: Can't say this works for me. When I try this I get an AttributeError "Cannot access callable attribute 'rolling' of 'DataFrameGroupby' object.

I can, however, do this:

`In[24]: df_test.sort_values(by=['PLAYER_ID', 'HITS'], ascending=True, inplace=True)
In[25]: df_test = df_test.groupby(['PLAYER_ID'], as_index=False).agg({'HITS': {'Rolling Avg HITS': lambda x: x[-3:].mean()}})
In[26]: df_test
Out[26]: 
  PLAYER_ID             HITS
            Rolling Avg HITS
0         A               50
1         B               22`

So long as its sorted beforehand won't this do the same?

Comment: What version of `pandas` are you using? The `rolling` object was introduced relatively recently, before that you would use `rolling_mean(1)` instead, so try that. As for the workaround: yes, that might work in this specific instance, but I'm not sure how well it would generalize.

Comment: Pandas 0.18.0  So that could be it. And thanks again for the help.