# Python Pandas: Computing Rolling-Mean for Filtered Data

Tags: python, pandas

I have some time series data which contains both day time and night time values. The time entries are parsed in DateTime format, and I have a routine that is able to determine the values corresponding to night periods.

For my purposes, I would like to compute the rolling mean, but only using night time values.

Is there an easy way of doing this?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Update: A slice through the dataframe looks like this:

```
0    Time                        Value
1    2016-02-16 08:40:14.133000  12
2    2016-02-16 11:25:14.133000  4
3    2016-02-16 23:45:14.133000  8
4    2016-03-16 08:40:14.002700  17
5    2016-03-16 23:45:14.133000  2
6    2016-03-16 23:50:14.133000  6
7    2016-03-16 23:55:14.133000  9
8    2016-04-16 08:40:14.133000  10
9    2016-04-16 11:20:14.133000  2
10   2016-04-16 12:40:14.133000  7
11   2016-04-16 23:45:14.133000  5
12   2016-05-16 08:40:14.002700  11
13   2016-05-16 23:40:14.133000  3
14   2016-05-16 23:50:14.133000  4
15   2016-06-16 08:40:14.002700  11
16   2016-06-16 10:30:14.002700  27
17   2016-06-16 23:25:14.133000  3
18   2016-06-16 23:30:14.133000  5
19   2016-07-16 08:40:14.002700  7
20   2016-07-16 11:15:14.002700  9
21   2016-07-16 23:45:14.133000  18
```

I am interested in computing the weekly rolling-mean for night values only. In my examples, night time is between 11pm and 5am.

Comment: can you give us an example of your data and if it is in a dataframe what format the dataframe looks like?

Comment: Please provide [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I have updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a column coding which night it is using `date` of pandas datetime series. And then use this column for a groupby to compute your rolling mean per week:

```
df.Time = pd.to_datetime(df.Time)
df['night'] = (df.Time.dt.hour>22) | (df.Time.dt.hour < 6)
df['date'] = df.Time.dt.date
idx = (df.night) & (df.Time.dt.hour>22)
df.loc[idx,'date'] = df.loc[idx,'date'].values + pd.DateOffset(1)
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df['rolling_mean'] = np.nan
df.loc[df.night,'rolling_mean'] = df.loc[df.night,'date'].apply(lambda x : df.loc[df.night & df.date.between(x-pd.DateOffset(3),x+pd.DateOffset(3)),'Value'].mean())
df.drop(['night','date'],1,inplace = True)


    Time                        Value   rolling_mean
1   2016-02-16 08:40:14.133000  12      NaN
2   2016-02-16 11:25:14.133000  4       NaN
3   2016-02-16 23:45:14.133000  8       8.000000
4   2016-03-16 08:40:14.002700  17      NaN
5   2016-03-16 23:45:14.133000  2       5.666667
6   2016-03-16 23:50:14.133000  6       5.666667
7   2016-03-16 23:55:14.133000  9       5.666667
8   2016-04-16 08:40:14.133000  10      NaN
9   2016-04-16 11:20:14.133000  2       NaN
10  2016-04-16 12:40:14.133000  7       NaN
11  2016-04-16 23:45:14.133000  5       5.000000
12  2016-05-16 08:40:14.002700  11      NaN
13  2016-05-16 23:40:14.133000  3       3.500000
14  2016-05-16 23:50:14.133000  4       3.500000
15  2016-06-16 08:40:14.002700  11      NaN
16  2016-06-16 10:30:14.002700  27      NaN
17  2016-06-16 23:25:14.133000  3       4.000000
18  2016-06-16 23:30:14.133000  5       4.000000
19  2016-07-16 08:40:14.002700  7       NaN
20  2016-07-16 11:15:14.002700  9       NaN
21  2016-07-16 23:45:14.133000  18      18.000000
```

It is a heavy way to do this and there is probably a more elegant and pythonic way to do it, but at least you have your output!

EDIT:

There must definitely be a better way to do it using [pandas.DataFrame.rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) on a subdataframe only containing the night rows. See [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15771472/pandas-rolling-mean-by-time-interval) for example.

Here is a suboptimal example:

```
df['night'] = (df.Time.dt.hour>22) | (df.Time.dt.hour < 6)
df['date'] = df.Time.dt.date
idx = (df.night) & (df.Time.dt.hour>22)
df.loc[idx,'date'] = df.loc[idx,'date'].values + pd.DateOffset(1)
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df = df.set_index('date').join(df.loc[df.night].set_index('date').resample("1d").Value.mean().rolling(window=3, min_periods=1).mean(),rsuffix="_rolling_mean").reset_index()
df.drop(['night','date'],1,inplace = True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually, what is being computed here is the daily mean per night, whereas what I need is the weekly rolling mean per night. In other words, for a given night, I would need to look at the mean for a week worth of night values centred around the current date. I think it is possible to obtain this from your "rolling_mean" column, by applying  further rolling calculations.

Comment: Ok my bad, using a filter in the `apply` you can get the rolling mean. I updated my answer accordingly, thanks for the precision!