# pandas groupby rolling mean/median with dropping missing values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, rolling-computation

How can get in pandas groupby rolling mean/median with dropping missing values? I.e. the output should drop missing values before calculating mean/median instead of giving me NaN if a missing value is present.

```py
import pandas as pd
t = pd.DataFrame(data={v.date:[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
                         'i0':[0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3],
                         'i1':['A']*12,
                         'x':[10.,20.,30.,np.nan,np.nan,21.,np.nan,41.,np.nan,np.nan,32.,42.]})
t.set_index([v.date,'i0','i1'], inplace=True)
t.sort_index(inplace=True)

print(t)
print(t.groupby('date').apply(lambda x: x.rolling(window=2).mean()))
```

gives

```
               x
date i0 i1      
0    0  A   10.0
     1  A   20.0
     2  A   30.0
     3  A    NaN
1    0  A    NaN
     1  A   21.0
     2  A    NaN
     3  A   41.0
2    0  A    NaN
     1  A    NaN
     2  A   32.0
     3  A   42.0

               x
date i0 i1      
0    0  A    NaN
     1  A   15.0
     2  A   25.0
     3  A    NaN
1    0  A    NaN
     1  A    NaN
     2  A    NaN
     3  A    NaN
2    0  A    NaN
     1  A    NaN
     2  A    NaN
     3  A   37.0
```

while I want the following for this example:

```
               x
date i0 i1      
0    0  A   10.0
     1  A   15.0
     2  A   25.0
     3  A   30.0
1    0  A    NaN
     1  A   21.0
     2  A   21.0
     3  A   41.0
2    0  A    NaN
     1  A    NaN
     2  A   32.0
     3  A   37.0
```

what I tried

```py
t.groupby('date').apply(lambda x: x.rolling(window=2).dropna().median())
```

and

```py
t.groupby('date').apply(lambda x: x.rolling(window=2).median(dropna=True))
```

(both raise exceptions, but maybe there exists something along the lines)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15771472/pandas-rolling-mean-by-time-interval, adding min_periods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for `min_periods`? Note that you don't need `apply`, call`GroupBy.Rolling` directly:

```
t.groupby('date', group_keys=False).rolling(window=2, min_periods=1).mean()
               x
date i0 i1      
0    0  A   10.0
     1  A   15.0
     2  A   25.0
     3  A   30.0
1    0  A    NaN
     1  A   21.0
     2  A   21.0
     3  A   41.0
2    0  A    NaN
     1  A    NaN
     2  A   32.0
     3  A   37.0
```

Comment: I feel like stack's server is acting up today , can not see the question in time :-(

Comment: @WeNYoBen Yeah same. Btw just sae your comment. Is this a dupe? I feel like it is close but the use case for min periods is slightly different here.

Comment: I do not think that is dup , since he have two problem , forget adding the min_periods and also rolling should not with apply

Comment: @cs95 I use apply since there is a [bug in pandas](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14013), which will only be fixed in pandas-0.25. Just look how messed up your output is if apply is not used (two 'date' index levels).

Comment: @S.V Didn't notice that, but fixed ;)