# Pandas groupby over fixed time period

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a list of customers, dates and scores:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
data = pd.DataFrame(
        np.array(
            [
                ["A", dt.datetime(2017, 12, 10), 10.0],
                ["A", dt.datetime(2018, 1, 10), 10.0],
                ["A", dt.datetime(2018, 1, 15), 11.0],
                ["A", dt.datetime(2018, 1, 16), 12.0],
                ["A", dt.datetime(2018, 1, 16), 13.0],
                ["B", dt.datetime(2018, 1, 16), 10.0],
                ["A", dt.datetime(2018, 3, 1), 10.0],
            ]
        ),
        columns=["Customer", "Date", "Score", "Result"],
    )

Customer    Date    Score
0   A   2017-12-10 00:00:00 10
1   A   2018-01-10 00:00:00 10
2   A   2018-01-15 00:00:00 11
3   A   2018-01-16 00:00:00 12
4   A   2018-01-16 00:00:00 13
5   B   2018-01-16 00:00:00 10
6   A   2018-03-01 00:00:00 10
```

For each customer I would like to calculate the average score for the last 14 days (including today). The result should look like:

```
    Customer    Date    Score   Result
0   A   2017-12-10 00:00:00 10  10
1   A   2018-01-10 00:00:00 10  10
2   A   2018-01-15 00:00:00 11  10.5
3   A   2018-01-16 00:00:00 12  11.5
4   A   2018-01-16 00:00:00 13  11.5
5   B   2018-01-16 00:00:00 10  10
6   A   2018-03-01 00:00:00 10  10
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas groupby rolling mean/median with dropping missing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56872205/pandas-groupby-rolling-mean-median-with-dropping-missing-values)

Comment: No, that's not it, but thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `Customer` and compute the `rolling` mean with window size of `14 days` on `Score`, then use [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to merge this rolling `avg` with dataframe `data`:

```
avg = data.set_index('Date').groupby('Customer').rolling('14d')['Score'].mean()
avg = avg[~avg.index.duplicated(keep='last')]

df = data.merge(avg.rename('Result'), left_on=['Customer', 'Date'], right_index=True)
```

Result:

```
print(df)
  Customer       Date Score  Result
0        A 2017-12-10    10    10.0
1        A 2018-01-10    10    10.0
2        A 2018-01-15    11    10.5
3        A 2018-01-16    12    11.5
4        A 2018-01-16    13    11.5
5        B 2018-01-16    10    10.0
6        A 2018-03-01    10    10.0
```