# how to avoid for loop using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
def moving_window(self, input_df: pd.DataFrame, previous_df: pd.DataFrame):
    comb_df = pd.concat([previous_df, input_df])
    results = pd.Series()
    for index, row in input_df.iterrows():
        start_ts = int(index) - self.duration * 1000
        current_df = comb_df.loc[(comb_df.index >= start_ts) & (comb_df.index <= int(index))]
        single_pred = self.another_function(current_df)
        if single_pred:
            results.loc[index] = single_pred
    return reults
```

Is there a way to convert the for loop into something more efficient ?

Comment: Are you familiar with [`pandas.DataFrame.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)? Just judging by your function name `moving_window`, it seems like it would be relevant.

Comment: What is the `type` of `self.duration` and `input_df.index`?

Comment: i tried to use rolling, but not sure how to set/override window param, basically i want to have set of rows between two timestamps

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp epoch timestamp(int64)

Comment: Have a look at [time offsets](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects) for using in your `.rolling`

Comment: sure ! thanks @JoshuaVoskamp

Comment: [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15771472/pandas-rolling-mean-by-time-interval) to a possibly-related question may help point you in the right direction