# Groupby and count with condition and get week start (from sunday) and week end from date column in Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset like below. I need to do count of ticket_id with status closed based on groupby and I need to get week start(sunday) and week end from ticket_time column.
**Input dataframe**

```
id       status     ticket_time         product         country
1260057   open     2021-10-03 01:20:00  Broadband       Grenada
2998178   open     2021-10-06 00:00:00  Fixed Voice     Bahamas
3762949  closed    2021-10-04 00:00:00  Fixed Voice     St Lucia
3766608  closed    2021-10-10 00:00:00  Broadband       St Lucia
3767125  closed    2021-10-03 00:00:00  TV              Antigua
etc.................
```

**Output dataframe** EXAMPLE:

```
country  product    week_startdate     week_enddate          Value
antigua     TV      2021-10-03 00:00:00 2021-10-10 00:00:00  Count(id) with status=closed
St Lucia    Broadband   ...         ....                  ...
St Lucia    Fixedvoice  ...         ....                  ...
```

For each country and each product I should get the count of id which is having closed status.
Is groupby country and product will work?

**INPUT Dataset**

```
{'ticket_id': [1260057,
  2998178,
  3762949,
  3766608,
  3767125,
  6050009,
  6050608,
  6050972,
  6052253,
  6053697,
  6053812,
  6053848,
  6053970,
  6054363,
  6054549,
  6055529,
  6057303,
  6057364,
  6058428,
  6101321,
  6103451,
  6103688,
  6105180,
  693170,
  1259365,
  1259466,
  1260843,
  3762579,
  3762778,
  3764140,
  3768850,
  6050528,
  6050595,
  6051099,
  6053704,
  6054013,
  6054582,
  6055323,
  6056096,
  6056363,
  6057701,
  6058251,
  6058323,
  6102386,
  6103121,
  6104844,
  6104935,
  692914,
  1260730,
  2997275],
 'status': ['open',
  'open',
  'closed',
  'closed',
  'closed',
  'closed',
  'open',
  'open',
  'closed',
  'open',
  'open',
  'closed',
  'open',
  'open',
  'open',
  'open',
  'open',
  'open',
  'open',
  'closed',
  'closed',
  'closed',
  'open',
  'open',
  'closed',
  'closed',
  'open',
  'closed',
  'closed',
  'closed',
  'open',
  'closed',
  'closed',
  'closed',
  'open',
  'open',
  'open',
  'open',
  'open',
  'open',
  'open',
  'open',
  'open',
  'cancelled',
  'open',
  'open',
  'open',
  'closed',
  'closed',
  'open'],
 'ticket_start_time': [Timestamp('2021-10-04 01:20:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-02 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-01 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-04 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-04 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-01 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-01 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-01 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-02 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-03 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-03 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-03 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-03 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-03 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-04 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-04 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-05 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-05 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-05 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-01 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-03 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-04 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-05 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-05 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-01 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-01 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-05 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-01 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-01 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-01 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-05 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-01 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-01 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-01 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-03 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-03 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-04 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-04 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-04 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-04 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-05 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-05 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-05 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-02 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-02 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-04 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-04 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-04 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-04 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-01 00:00:00')],
 'product_type': ['Broadband',
  'Fixed Voice',
  'Fixed Voice',
  'Broadband',
  'TV',
  'TV',
  'Broadband',
  'Broadband',
  'Broadband',
  'Broadband',
  'Broadband',
  'Broadband',
  'Broadband',
  'Broadband',
  'Broadband',
  'Broadband',
  'Broadband',
  'Broadband',
  'TV',
  'TV',
  'Broadband',
  'Broadband',
  'Broadband',
  'Broadband',
  'Fixed Voice',
  'Broadband',
  'Fixed Voice',
  'TV',
  'Broadband',
  'Broadband',
  'Broadband',
  'Broadband',
  'Broadband',
  'Broadband',
  'Broadband',
  'TV',
  'Fixed Voice',
  'TV',
  'TV',
  'TV',
  'TV',
  'TV',
  'Broadband',
  'Broadband',
  'Broadband',
  'Broadband',
  'Broadband',
  'Broadband',
  'Fixed Voice',
  'Fixed Voice'],
 'org_country': ['Grenada',
  'Bahamas',
  'St Lucia',
  'St Lucia',
  'Antigua',
  'Jamaica',
  'Jamaica',
  'Jamaica',
  'Jamaica',
  'Jamaica',
  'Jamaica',
  'Jamaica',
  'Jamaica',
  'Jamaica',
  'Jamaica',
  'Jamaica',
  'Jamaica',
  'Jamaica',
  'Jamaica',
  'Trinidad',
  'Trinidad',
  'Trinidad',
  'Trinidad',
  'Curacao',
  'Grenada',
  'Grenada',
  'Grenada',
  'St Lucia',
  'St Lucia',
  'St Vincent',
  'St Lucia',
  'Jamaica',
  'Jamaica',
  'Jamaica',
  'Jamaica',
  'Jamaica',
  'Jamaica',
  'Jamaica',
  'Jamaica',
  'Jamaica',
  'Jamaica',
  'Jamaica',
  'Jamaica',
  'Trinidad',
  'Trinidad',
  'Trinidad',
  'Trinidad',
  'Curacao',
  'Grenada',
  'Bahamas']}
```

Comment: @Phil Leh I've been referring to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70182295/how-to-calculate-monthly-and-weekly-averages-from-a-dataframe-using-python. But not getting for my case. Can you pls help me on this.

Comment: can you describe a bit further what your ideal output is?  Do you also need to group by week?

Comment: My expected output is as above example. Please see above OUTPUTD DATAFRAME EXAMPLE. @PierreD..Yes only one week startdate and week enddate for each country and product.

Comment: The example is ambiguous because there is only one row for 'Antigua'. You could improve this by giving a few more and showing what your aggregation logic should be. The section "Output getting from below code" makes no sense: there is no code, and the data is way too big for us to understand what you have in mind.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We are all wasting time trying to understand what exactly you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modified answer

After many explanations, it seems that the OP is looking for week start and end as a result of aggregate, not as a grouping.

Therefore, here is the modified answer:

```py
weekday = 6  # Sunday
wo = pd.offsets.Week(weekday=weekday, normalize=True)

t = df['ticket_start_time'] + wo
gbcols = ['org_country', 'product_type']
agg_dict = {
    'ticket_id': 'count',
    'week_startdate': 'first',
    'week_enddate': 'last',
}
out = (
    df
    .assign(week_startdate=t - wo, week_enddate=t)
    .groupby(['ticket_id', 'status'] + gbcols).agg(agg_dict)
    .query("status == 'closed'").groupby(gbcols).agg(agg_dict)
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={'ticket_id': 'Value'})
)
```

From the provided 'input data', we get:

```py
>>> out
   org_country product_type  Value week_startdate week_enddate
0      Antigua           TV      1     2021-10-03   2021-10-10
1      Curacao    Broadband      1     2021-10-03   2021-10-10
2      Grenada    Broadband      1     2021-09-26   2021-10-03
3      Grenada  Fixed Voice      2     2021-09-26   2021-10-10
4      Jamaica    Broadband      5     2021-09-26   2021-10-10
5      Jamaica           TV      1     2021-09-26   2021-10-03
6     St Lucia    Broadband      2     2021-09-26   2021-10-10
7     St Lucia  Fixed Voice      1     2021-09-26   2021-10-03
8     St Lucia           TV      1     2021-09-26   2021-10-03
9   St Vincent    Broadband      1     2021-09-26   2021-10-03
10    Trinidad    Broadband      2     2021-10-03   2021-10-10
11    Trinidad           TV      1     2021-09-26   2021-10-03
```

#### Explanation

First the trick of adding / then subtracting the Week offset `wo` gets around the problem of subtracting an offset when the date is *at* the offset boundary.  For example:

```py
t = pd.to_datetime([
    '2021-10-02', '2021-10-03', '2021-10-03 01:00',
    '2021-10-04', '2021-10-09 23:59:59', '2021-10-10']
)
>>> pd.DataFrame(dict(t=t, ws=t + wo - wo, we=t + wo))
                    t         ws         we
0 2021-10-02 00:00:00 2021-09-26 2021-10-03
1 2021-10-03 00:00:00 2021-10-03 2021-10-10
2 2021-10-03 01:00:00 2021-10-03 2021-10-10
3 2021-10-04 00:00:00 2021-10-03 2021-10-10
4 2021-10-09 23:59:59 2021-10-03 2021-10-10
5 2021-10-10 00:00:00 2021-10-10 2021-10-17
```

Next, we want the count distinct of `ticket_id` where the status is `'closed'`. This is a bit trickier. We do it with two groupby. The first one is to tally the counts for each `(ticket, status)` (and all other grouping columns) group. There could be multiple instances of the same ticket being open or closed, but we want to disregard that.

```py
tmp = (
    df
    .assign(week_startdate=t - wo, week_enddate=t)
    .groupby(['ticket_id', 'status'] + gbcols)
    .agg(agg_dict)
)
>>> tmp.head()
                                           ticket_id week_startdate  \
ticket_id status org_country product_type                             
692914    closed Curacao     Broadband             1     2021-10-03   
693170    open   Curacao     Broadband             1     2021-10-03   
1259365   closed Grenada     Fixed Voice           1     2021-09-26   
1259466   closed Grenada     Broadband             1     2021-09-26   
1260057   open   Grenada     Broadband             1     2021-10-03   

                                          week_enddate  
ticket_id status org_country product_type               
692914    closed Curacao     Broadband      2021-10-10  
693170    open   Curacao     Broadband      2021-10-10  
1259365   closed Grenada     Fixed Voice    2021-10-03  
1259466   closed Grenada     Broadband      2021-10-03  
1260057   open   Grenada     Broadband      2021-10-10
```

Finally, we now simply aggregate again, but only grouping on the `gbcols` columns, and where status is 'closed' in that tally, giving us the complete expression above.

#### Addendum

The OP would like to convert the `week_startdate` and end date to appear as strings, with full `H:M:S` resolution. For this:

```py
for k in ['week_startdate', 'week_enddate']:
    out[k] = out[k].dt.strftime('%F %T')
```

And now:

```py
>>> out
   org_country product_type  Value       week_startdate         week_enddate
0      Antigua           TV      1  2021-10-03 00:00:00  2021-10-10 00:00:00
1      Curacao    Broadband      1  2021-10-03 00:00:00  2021-10-10 00:00:00
2      Grenada    Broadband      1  2021-09-26 00:00:00  2021-10-03 00:00:00
3      Grenada  Fixed Voice      2  2021-09-26 00:00:00  2021-10-10 00:00:00
4      Jamaica    Broadband      5  2021-09-26 00:00:00  2021-10-10 00:00:00
5      Jamaica           TV      1  2021-09-26 00:00:00  2021-10-03 00:00:00
6     St Lucia    Broadband      2  2021-09-26 00:00:00  2021-10-10 00:00:00
7     St Lucia  Fixed Voice      1  2021-09-26 00:00:00  2021-10-03 00:00:00
8     St Lucia           TV      1  2021-09-26 00:00:00  2021-10-03 00:00:00
9   St Vincent    Broadband      1  2021-09-26 00:00:00  2021-10-03 00:00:00
10    Trinidad    Broadband      2  2021-10-03 00:00:00  2021-10-10 00:00:00
11    Trinidad           TV      1  2021-09-26 00:00:00  2021-10-03 00:00:00
```

Comment: Really thanks for your valuable response.

Comment: I should get the week start and end date in datetime format. I tried with (format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)..But getting error. Can you pls help

Comment: you mean in the output? This is just a formatting issue. The columns are indeed full resolution Timestamps.

Comment: for example, try `out.to_dict(orient='records')` to see the Timestamps. If you just want to convert to str, you can also use `out['week_startdate'].dt.strftime('%F %T')` etc.

Comment: yes In the output I'm getting the week start and end date as str type .But ideally it should be like this 2021-10-02 00:00:00 in this date time format

Comment: Can you pls add that to your code. I'm not getting the weekstart and end date  as @Pierre D

Comment: Ok, please see Addendum.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! @Pierre D

Comment: Sure. If this addresses all your concerns, please don't forget to accept and uptick.

Comment: yes @PierreD But Can you pls explain why we are getting multiple rows for each country/product. I'm getting confused there.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your problem. I thought you wanted a per-week aggregate as well. Is that incorrect? What is the precise meaning of `week_startdate` and `week_enddate` in your desired output?

Comment: Yes, I need week start date and end date from ticket_start_time of that particular row. It is right..but I want to know why it is returning two rows with different strt and end date for same product/country. @Pierre D

Comment: Sorry -- do you need the week start and end for the overall aggregate (group by `(country, product)`), or do you need to group by week as well so that you have a break down by `(week, country, product)`?

Comment: first one is right.. So I need weekstart and weekend for (groupby( country, product)) with (count of ticket id where status is closed as Value) @Pierre D

Comment: I rewrote the answer based on this. It would have saved both you and us quite a bit of time if you had started with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It is important to describe precisely the questions you have, highlighting corner cases, the logic of a desired result in the example, etc.

Comment: Really Thanks you so much for your effort. Sorry for that, I will make sure my question will be more precise from next time. @Pierre D

Comment: The solution is really helpful.. But I need to achieve other usecases which I have created as another question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70459619/groupby-with-condition-and-get-week-start-from-sunday-and-week-endsaturday-i . Can you pls help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
def week_start_day(s):
    return s - (pd.to_timedelta((s.dt.weekday + 1)%7, unit='D'))

def week_end_day(s):
    return s + pd.to_timedelta(7-(s.dt.weekday+2)%7, unit='D')

df['ticket_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ticket_time'])

df = df[df['status'] == 'closed'].groupby(['country', 'product']).agg(week_startdate = pd.NamedAgg(column='ticket_time', aggfunc=week_start_day),
                                                                      week_enddate = pd.NamedAgg(column='ticket_time', aggfunc=week_end_day),
                                                                      Value = pd.NamedAgg(column='id', aggfunc="size"))
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

`OUTPUT`

```
    country      product week_startdate week_enddate  Value
0   Antigua           TV     2021-10-03   2021-10-09      1
1  St Lucia    Broadband     2021-10-10   2021-10-16      1
2  St Lucia  Fixed Voice     2021-10-03   2021-10-09      1
```

`Setup`

```
data = {'id': [1260057, 2998178, 3762949, 3766608, 3767125],
          'status': ['open', 'open', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed'],
          'ticket_time': ['2021-10-03 01:20:00', '2021-10-06 00:00:00', '2021-10-04 00:00:00',
                          '2021-10-10 00:00:00', '2021-10-03 00:00:00'],
          'product': ['Broadband', 'Fixed Voice', 'Fixed Voice', 'Broadband', 'TV'],
          'country': ['Grenada', 'Bahamas', 'St Lucia', 'St Lucia', 'Antigua']}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

Comment: Thanks much! But I'm getting week_startdate and enddate as unhashable type: 'DatetimeArray' . I should get only one start date , but it is consisting of array

Comment: Can you please post output of `df.head(50).to_json(orient='records')` so that i can check it on your dataframe. Its working fine for me for the data you posted in question'

Comment: I'm getting this error when I try to use df.head(50).to_json(orient='records')
OverflowError: Maximum recursion level reached.

Comment: But when I work with large set of data ,it is giving me like above! (Pls check updated question). Can you pls help me why I'm facing this. @Muhammed Hassan

Comment: Plz post the output of `df.to_dict('list')`

Comment: Please check my updated question. I have updated my output in list @Muhammed Hassan

Comment: I need the output of your original dataframe.

Comment: I updated the output of my original dataframe @Muhammed Hassan

Comment: Please post the output of your `Input dataframe` as you posted in the question above. You are posting the result of output dataframe

Comment: try posting this: `df.head(50).to_dict('list')`

Comment: Yes. I have updated my input dataset above. Please check @Muhammad Hassan

Comment: Apparently, the reason you are getting arrays in `week_startdate` and `week_startdate` is that for a certain combination of `product_type` and `org_country` you have multiple rows where `status` is `closed`. For example, for `country: Grenada` and `product_type: Fixed Voice` you have two rows where `status` is `closed`

Comment: Yes, I understood now.. Thanks much for your effort. Either I can go with your approach(with array of dates) or @Pierre D approach

Comment: FYI, the answer I provide doesn't care how many times a ticket is 'closed'. It counts just one for a ticket closed, no matter how many times it appears in the df. That's essentially a COUNT DISTINCT.

Comment: yes.. But Can you pls explain why we are getting multiple rows for each country/product. I'm getting confused there. @Pierre D

Comment: @Muhammad Hassan.. Is there any way to handle this arrays of dates..because everything is fine expect that date part.